# Combine two columns and search on them

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have this query in which we can search based on `first name and last name`. And it works fine like this:

```
  |> where(
  [user],
   ilike(user.first_name, ^string) or (user.last_name, ^string) 
 )
```

It works fine. Now I want to search on full name that is `first_name + last_name`. I tried this approach of Postgres. If I pass both first name and last name in this query it's returning empty.

```
 |> where(
  [user],
   ilike(user.first_name, ^string) or ilike(user.last_name, ^string) or ilike(fragment("(?)||' '||(?)", user.first_name, user.last_name), ^string)
 )
```

But it doesn’t work. it’s returning no result.
Is there anything I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: The syntax seems to be correct. I think the problem is on the SQL level. Make sure your queries work properly using raw SQL. You can play with PG pattern matching operators to make sure stuff works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

The [arguably] more common approach in such a case would be to use [`Ecto.Query.or_where/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#or_where/3)

```rb
|> where([user], ilike(user.first_name, ^string))
|> or_where([user], ilike(user.last_name, ^string))
|> or_where([user], ilike(fragment("CONCAT((?), ' ',(?))",
             user.first_name, user.last_name), ^string))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
         ilike(fragment(“CONCAT((?), ’ ',(?))”, user.first_name, user.last_name), ^string)
```

does the trick.